# Android volley saving json data to string for sharing (onPostExecute method for volley?)

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am using volley library to get data from an api in JSON format, and it works like a charm. I ask for JSON file, i get a response, i parse that respons and populte the views in activity.

Now, i have a button to share the data using Intetnt.ACTION_SEND and putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT) that takes string as the 2nd parameter.

The problem is, i make a string variable and append data in that string variable inside volley on response method. but as volley makes a new thread for getting data from api the string is not updated and Intetnt.EXTRA_TEXT sends an empty string.

I want to ask, if there is anything similer to onPostExecute method for volley? where i can set the data to some variables after the thread is done processing. or any alternate methods to do the same.

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, bookSearchString, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray bookArray = response
                                .getJSONArray("items");
                        JSONObject bookObject = bookArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        try {
                            bookSelfLink = bookObject.getString("selfLink");
                            JsonObjectRequest newJsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                                    Request.Method.GET, bookSelfLink, null,
                                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                        public void onResponse(
                                                JSONObject response) {
                                            try {
                                                JSONObject newBookObject = response
                                                        .getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                                                try {
                                                    dBookPages.setText("Pages - "
                                                            + newBookObject
                                                                    .getString("pageCount"));
                                                    eMailText = eMailText + newBookObject
                                                                    .getString("pageCount")); 
                                                } catch (JSONException jse) {
                                                    dBookPages
                                                            .setText("Pages not found");
                                                    jse.printStackTrace();
                                                }

                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onErrorResponse(
                                                VolleyError error) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method
                                            // stub

                                        }
                                    });
                            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(
                                    newJsObjRequest, tag_json_obj);
                        } catch (JSONException jse) {
                            jse.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest,
            tag_json_obj);
```

Comment: `onResponse` runs on UI, post your code!

Comment: okay, gimme few mins

Comment: i have updated que with code.

Comment: `The problem is, i make a string variable and append data in that string variable inside volley on response method. but as volley makes a new thread for getting data from api the string is not updated and Intetnt.EXTRA_TEXT sends an empty string.` i think the problem is not in the code you have post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 work around for the record.

1) make network call on button click -> wait for response -> fire intent inside onResponse with bundled data.

2) pass url as string in bundle -> call intent for new activity -> make network request pars data.

Answer (score 1):

from the Volley v1.0.0 Documentation:

```
    public boolean hasHadResponseDelivered()
```

Returns true if this request has had a response delivered for it.

I hope that this answer would help someone with the same question.